# Operating door lock from Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I need to install a smart wi-fi switch to operate an electronic door lock that can be opened from anywhere using the mobile app. There are a lot of options available for smart wi-fi switches however, once these switches are linked to Alexa/ Google assistant, they can be operated (open the door) by using just a voice command. Is there any way to activate an additional mobile device authentication in Alexa/ Google assistant before they switch on a particular switch?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a programming question?

Comment: I am not sure if this can only be done through programming. I am a non-programer, and I thought there might be any Alexa-skill or GUI-based configuration that can help in achieving this objective.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform. If you aren't looking for a programming solution, it doesn't belong here, and you need to delete this. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are programming your own lock to work with Google Assistant, you would need to implement [secondary user verification](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/secondary-user-verification) within your application to have the additional authentication layer you're looking for. The [`pinNeeded` challenge](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/secondary-user-verification#pinneeded) would be the most secure option to implement on the [`LockUnlock` trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/lockunlock).

If you're just buying a 3rd party lock/switch to install, that functionality would only be available if the manufacturer has implemented it.